# RegEx & PHP: last appearance with $ , only working in online tester

Tags: php, html, regex

So I got the following HTML Code:

```
[et_pb_section admin_label="section"]  


<h2>abcdefghijkl - abcdefghijklmno</h2>  
<p> </p>
<p>abcdefghi<strong> abcdefghijkl</strong> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz.</p>
<p><br /><br /><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>abcdefghij</strong></span></p>
<p><br />abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz.<br /> <br /><br />
<span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>abcdefghi</strong>
</span></p>
<p><br />abcdefghijklmano</p>
      <br /><br />
      <div id="termine">
    <div>
        <strong>abcdefghikla - 12345678</strong>
        <p>
        <a href="/just-another-url.html">abcdefghijklmnopqrst <br />
abcdefghijklmnopqrst >>></a>
        </p>
    </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

and I want to replace the last closing `</div>` with another piece of code `[/et_pb_section]`.

So I have tried in one of the many online regex testers and cameup with this

`$content= preg_replace("/<\/div>$/", $et_pb_section_ENDTAG, $content);` where `$et_pb_section_ENDTAG` is 
`$et_pb_section_ENDTAG='[/et_pb_section]';`.

When using the online tester everything works fine and the last `</div>` gets replaced but inside my php script it is not working. nothing happens, no error, no nothing. The HTML code stays the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

EDIT: Oh, I almost forgot, when I get rid of the $ and use RegEx Option `D` ( matches only at the end of string) then all three closing `</div>` get replaced. So I guess something is wrong with the `$`

Comment: Maybe there is whitespace between `</div>` and the strings ending? You should use a parser.

Comment: You could catch whitespace characters with `\s`, so your regex would be `<\/div>\s*$`, but like chris already said: regexing HTML code is no good.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Use DOMDocument and DOMXPath, find the div, build a fragment with the two text nodes (opening and closing brackets) and all the children elements, and replace the div.

Comment: what would be a proper way to exchange HTML Tags with other custom Tags. Since my script was going to do a lot of this Tag swapping. @CasimiretHippolyte my first idea was to do it with DomDoc and DOMXpath but when I tried my nodeValue didn't return no HTML Tags so I let go of it. How can I get it to show HTML Tags

Comment: @b101: i will post an example.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with `$`. It's there to find the last occurrence of `<div>`. If you get rid of it then it will find all occurrences of `<div>` right from the beginning.

Comment: @noob well.. that is how it is supposed to work. but actually, when I get rid of it it replaces all `</div>` (what is perfectly correct) but when I set `$` nothing happens...

Comment: @b101: Out of curiosity: what if you use `'/<\/div>$/'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example with [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) and [`DOMDocumentFragment`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumentfragment.php) that replaces the first div tag with an "admin_label" attribute with the value "section" (feel free to adapt to your real needs):

```
$html = <<<'EOD'
<div admin_label="section">
    <p>abdefghij</p>
    <p>klmnopqrs</p>
    <p>tuvwxyz01</p>
    <ul>
        <li>2345</li>
        <li>6789</li>
    </ul>
</div>
EOD;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$divNode = $xp->query('(//div[@admin_label="section"])[1]')->item(0);

$open = $dom->createTextNode('[et_pb_section admin_label="section"]');
$close = $dom->createTextNode('[/et_pb_section]');

$fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendChild($open);
foreach ($divNode->childNodes as $childNode) {
    $fragment->appendChild($childNode->cloneNode(true));
}
$fragment->appendChild($close);

$divNode->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $divNode);

echo $dom->saveHTML();

libxml_clear_errors();
```

Note: in real life, you need to check if the XPath query returns something before continue.

Comment: YOU, are a lifesaver :D thank you very much!
this is new to me, I've never seen those before  `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);`

The documentation says `Sets HTML_PARSE_NOIMPLIED flag, which turns off the automatic adding of implied html/body... elements.` as well as `Sets HTML_PARSE_NODEFDTD flag, which prevents a default doctype being added when one is not found.` - but what does that actually mean? I'm not really getting it. Everything else I seem to understand, but would have never came up with it :) thank you

Comment: @b101: By default, when it's missing, `DOMDocument::loadHTML` add automatically a doctype to the html code (the doctype html4 if I remember well) and it add too the "html" and "body" tags. These two options prevent this. Otherwise you will obtain: `<!DOCTYPE .....><html><body>[et_pb.....]<p>abdefghij</p>....[/et_pb_section]</body></html>`